# UIView animation not performing immediately after the first run.

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

So basically I have two methods that I run when the user clicks an Annotation in the map.

```
- (void) methodA{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:kRequestButtonAnimationDuration animations:^(void){
            self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-(self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height - self.button.frame.origin.y)); }]; }

- (void) methodB:(double)value andBoolean:(BOOL) boolean{    
     if (self.timer) {
         [self.timer invalidate];
         self.timer = nil;
       }

        if (boolean) {
          self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:value target:self selector:@selector(pullButtonUp) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        }   else{
          self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:value target:self selector:@selector(showTabBar) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}}

-(void)pullButtonUp{
    [(LLTabBarViewController*)self.tabBarController showTabBarAnimated];}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{

[self methodA];

[self methodB:2.0 andBoolean:TRUE];

}
```

So during the first time I select an annotation, it works well: it runs methodA, then methodB after 2.0 seconds.

But when I try it again, it runs both A and B at the same time (basically methodA waits 2.0 seconds to execute).

Could this be related to Loops?

How should I track this problem? Any instrument? Which one?

I am a bit lost, help me please!

Comment: Why are you using timers here? That seems like a huge mistake. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Keep in mind that animation is asynchronous. If you say "animate this" and then immediately say "animate that", "this" and "that" will happen simultaneously; it doesn't magically wait until the end of "this" before starting "that". You can easily arrange that, but you must arrange it. And timers are _not_ how to do it.

Comment: I want methodB to fire 2 seconds after methodA. How should I implement this then? It works well like this for the first time.

Comment: "I want methodB to fire 2 seconds after methodA". Really? Okay...  However, your code is so convoluted I'm worried that that _isn't_ really what you want to do. But if you're sure, then the simplest way to do that is to have methodA call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` on methodB. But right now method B is all about timers, so I don't believe that that's what you _really really_ want to do. Please describe the _overall effect_ you are _really_ trying to achieve. Because I assure you, from your code, no one could ever guess what it is.

Comment: I changed it and it acts exactly the same. First time I select it works, second time they both execute at the same time.

Comment: So basically, methodA shows a button after 2 seconds methodB shows another button and moves the first button. (the second move of this button is not reflected - neither relevant - in the code above)

Comment: "First time I select it works, second time they both execute at the same time" Because you've still got them both in `didSelectAnnotationView`. That's the problem. You need `didSelectAnnotationView` to call _just methodA_. Let methodA call methodB with the two-second delay. This can't fail. Get rid of the timers. Get rid of the boolean. All that is just spaghetti. Just go `didSelect` -> methodA -> methodB-after-delay.

Comment: it didn't work either. it must be something else. I am using timers so I can invalidate the previous call (in case the user performs this action twice or more)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    BOOL arbitraryBool = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                     animations:^{
                         self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-(self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height - self.button.frame.origin.y));
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {

                             if (arbitraryBool) {
                                 [weakSelf pullButtonUp];
                             } else {
                                 [weakSelf showTabBar];
                             }
                         }
                     }]:
}
```

Comment: That is not what I intend to do but I appreciate your help